# What is a better way to write HTML than document.write in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rss

I found working JavaScript code to feed into a jQuery mobile app [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20344124/rss-feed-in-jquery-mobile-not-loading-correctly) and made some minor modifications to it.

As I am very new to JavaScript - currently in the beginning of the JavaScript course at codeacademy.com - I didn't realize that `document.write` is not the best way to output/build your HTML.

When the `.js` file is loaded it's like a blank page which I believe is due to  `document.write`. When I refresh, the RSS feed displays correctly. I'm having a very hard time figuring out what code I need to use to replace the `document.write` portions.

I've seen `document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='test'` but not quite sure how to use this to replace document.write in the code below.

If someone would provide the alternative code for document.write in one of the sections below before the JSON code I would be extremely grateful.

```
/* configuration */
var maxLength = 10;

/* writing HTML */
document.write(
/* page begins */
  '<div id="news" data-role="page" data-theme="a" data-title="NEWS">' +
  '  <div data-role="content">' +
  '    <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" id="dynamiclist" data-inset="true">'
);
for (var i=1; i<=maxLength; i++){
  document.write(
    '<li id="list' + i + '"><a href="#article' + i + '" id="link' + i + '">&nbsp;</a></li>'
  );
}
document.write(
  '    </ul>' +
  '  </div>' +
  '</div>'
);
for (i=1; i<=maxLength; i++){
  document.write(
    '<div data-role="page" id="article' + i + '">' +
    '  <div data-role="content">' +
    '  <h3 id="articleHeader' + i + '">&nbsp;</h3>' +
    '    <div id="articleContent' + i + '" class="articleContent">' +
    '    <p id="articleDate' + i + '" class="articleDate"></p></div>' +
    '    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">' +
'      <a href="news.html" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-grid ui-btn-inline">News</a>' +
    '      <a href="#article' + String(i-1) + '" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l"' +
    '        data-inline="true" class="prevButton">Prev</a>' +
    '      <a href="#article' + String(i+1) + '" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r"' +
    '        data-inline="true" class="nextButton" data-iconpos="right">Next</a>' +
    '    </div>' +
    '  </div>' +
    '</div>'
  );
}
/* JSONP */
$(function(){
  getOnlineFeed('http://rss.cnn.com/rss/money_news_economy.rss');
});
/* functions */
var getOnlineFeed = function(url) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.setAttribute('src', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?callback=listEntries&hl=ja&output=json-in-script&q='
                  + encodeURIComponent(url)
                  + '&v=1.0&num=' + maxLength);
  script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
  document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);
};
var getOfflineFeed = function(url) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.setAttribute('src', url);
  script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
  document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);
};
var listEntries = function(json) {
  if (!json.responseData.feed.entries) return false;
  $('#widgetTitle').text(json.responseData.feed.title);
  var articleLength =json.responseData.feed.entries.length;
  articleLength = (articleLength > maxLength) ? maxLength : articleLength;
  for (var i = 1; i <= articleLength ; i++) {
    var entry = json.responseData.feed.entries[i-1];
    $('#link' + i).text(entry.title);
    $('#articleDate' + i).text(entry.pubdate);
    $('#articleHeader' + i).text(entry.title);
    $('#openButton' + i).attr('href', entry.link);
    $('#articleContent' + i).append(entry.content);
  }
  $('#article1 .prevButton').remove();
  $('#article' + articleLength + ' .nextButton').remove();
  if (articleLength < maxLength) {
    for (i = articleLength + 1; i <= maxLength; i++) {
      $('#list' + i).remove();
      $('#article' + i).remove();
    }
  }
};
$('#PageRefresh').click(function() { 
       location.reload();
    });
```

Comment: I really wish people would stop teaching `document.write()`. You should use the DOM to make those elements, and read up on the `document.write()` is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I did not read the question carefully enough the first time - I now see that you're already using jQuery, but not before you do your DOM manipulation. So the rest of the answer stands - use .html() and manipulate the DOM only after the document is ready.

Here's my suggestion. Full disclaimer: this is not the only way to do it nor is it necessarily the "best" way to do it. I daresay it would be the most common way to do it, however.

1. Use jQuery - it will make your life so much easier. http://jquery.com
2. Make sure you do your DOM (Document Object Model) manipulation (inserting HTML elements to your document is a type of DOM manipulation, although I'm not sure that document.write() is) after it is ready. jQuery provides a nice method to do just this. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

   ```
   $(function() {
       // Handler for .ready() called
   });
   ```
3. Use the `.html()` function within jQuery to write to your `<body>` element or a `<div>` element that you write directly in your HTML file. http://api.jquery.com/html/

HTML

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

jQuery

```
var page = "This should have the HTML you want to insert";
$(function() {
    $("#content").html(page);
});
```

Comment: If your answer requires a disclaimer, you should rethink your answer.

Comment: @RUJordan - I guess I wasn't clear previously. This code works correctly and will load the RSS feed but only after displaying a white page that shows only the bullets (no feed list items) and the "News." "Next" and "Previous" links. Once I click on the "News" link it loads the feed items and is styled correctly. It  seems to be the document.write code that builds the HTML. `document.write(
    '<li id="list' + i + '"><a href="#article' + i + '" id="link' + i + '">&nbsp;</a></li>` This is what I would like help fixing.
  );